# Ruby и Nokogiri формирование XML

Tags: xml, ruby, gems, nokogiri

Добрый день
есть классы:

```
class Movement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flight

  scope :book_weekly, -> { where(status_code: 'BKD').where(moved_at: (Date.today..(Date.today + 1.week))) }
end

class Flight < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movements
end

class WeeklyBriefCollector

  def initialize
    flights_ids = Movement.book_weekly.unscope(:order).map {|m| m.flight_id}.compact.uniq
    @flights = Flight.where(id: flights_ids, departure_time: (Date.today..(Date.today + 1.week)))
  end

  def xml
    flights = flights_data
    unless flights.empty?
      xml = Nokogiri::XML "
      <FLIGHTS DateFrom='#{Date.today}' DateTo='#{Date.today + 1.week}'>
        #{flights}
      </FLIGHTS>
      "
      xml.to_xml
    end
  end

  def flights_data
    @flights.map do |flight|
      unless flight.movements.empty?
        "<FLIGHT date='#{flight.departure_time.to_date}' no='#{flight.flight_number}' carrier='#{flight.airline}'>
          <leg num='1' origin='#{flight.origin_apt}' destination='#{flight.destination_apt}' Volume_Adv='#{flight.movements.sum(:volume)}' Weight_Adv='#{flight.movements.sum(:weight)}' Pieces_Adv='#{flight.movements.sum(:pieces)}'/>
        </FLIGHT>"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

в ответ я получаю:

```
#=>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FLIGHTS DateFrom="2016-07-08" DateTo="2016-07-15">
    [
      "<FLIGHT date="2016-07-10" no="701" carrier="U6">
        <leg num="1" origin="SVX" destination="PRG" Volume_Adv="0.0" Weight_Adv="200.0" Pieces_Adv="1"/>
      </FLIGHT>",
      "<FLIGHT date="2016-07-14" no="701" carrier="U6">
        <leg num="1" origin="SVX" destination="PRG" Volume_Adv="0.0" Weight_Adv="400.0" Pieces_Adv="2"/>
      </FLIGHT>"
    ]
</FLIGHTS>
```

Суть в том что в автоматическом режиме будет запускаться `WeeklyBriefCollector.new.xml` и отправляться на определенный почтовый ящик, для дальнейшей обработки другой программой
внутри xml у меня остаются символы массива, и вообще я полагаю, что я набросал все это далеко не наилучшим образом.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как наилучшим образом реализовать данную задачу?

и по итогу получить xml такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FLIGHTS DateFrom="2016-07-08" DateTo="2016-07-15">
  <FLIGHT date="2016-07-10" no="701" carrier="U6">
    <leg num="1" origin="SVX" destination="PRG" Volume_Adv="0.0" Weight_Adv="200.0" Pieces_Adv="1"/>
  </FLIGHT>
  <FLIGHT date="2016-07-14" no="701" carrier="U6">
    <leg num="1" origin="SVX" destination="PRG" Volume_Adv="0.0" Weight_Adv="400.0" Pieces_Adv="2"/>
  </FLIGHT>
</FLIGHTS>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил как-то так

```
  def xml
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new { |xml|
      xml.FLIGHTS('DateFrom' => Date.today, 'DateTo' => (Date.today + 1.week)) do
        @flights.map do |flight|
          xml.FLIGHT('date' => flight.departure_time.to_date, 'no' => flight.flight_number, 'carrier' => flight.airline) do
            xml.len('num' => 1,  'origin' => flight.origin_apt, 'destination' => flight.destination_apt, 'Volume_Adv' => flight.movements.sum(:volume), 'Weight_Adv' => flight.movements.sum(:weight), 'Pieces_Adv' => flight.movements.sum(:pieces))
          end
        end
      end
    }
    builder.to_xml
  end
```

Ответ получаю такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FLIGHTS DateFrom="2016-07-08" DateTo="2016-07-15">
  <FLIGHT date="2016-07-10" no="701" carrier="U6">
    <len num="1" origin="SVX" destination="PRG" Volume_Adv="0.0" Weight_Adv="200.0" Pieces_Adv="1"/>
  </FLIGHT>
  <FLIGHT date="2016-07-14" no="701" carrier="U6">
    <len num="1" origin="SVX" destination="PRG" Volume_Adv="0.0" Weight_Adv="400.0" Pieces_Adv="2"/>
  </FLIGHT>
</FLIGHTS>
```